# Reading Large XML files in C# Returns null when looking for an element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I need to read in a large XML file but everything I have tried comes back NULL.

```
public void readXml()
{
  XElement xelement = XElement.Load(DewesoftDevices.xmlFileName);
  IEnumerable<XElement> devices = xelement.Elements("Devices");

  foreach (var device in devices)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(device);
  }
}
```

Here is a portion of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataFileSetup>
    <System Name="Local">
        <SysInfo>
         'Stuff in here that I dont need
        </SysInfo>
        <DewesoftSetup>
           <Devices>
               <StartStoreTime>43861.6768385532</StartStoreTime>
               <SampleRate>100</SampleRate>
               <BlockSize>1000</BlockSize>
               <IBRate>10</IBRate>
           </Devices>
        </DewesoftSetup>
    </System>
</DataFileSetup>
```

I dont know if it matters but these are far down the in the file.

Comment: I'm more interested in what's at the start, actually. A common mistake is forgetting to account for XML namespaces (`xmlns`).

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] and make sure small data sample (similar to one already in the post) actually demonstrates the problem. In particular make sure to provide all relevant namespaces for nodes you are trying to query for.

Comment: I have added more XML code.

Comment: What is the size of the XML file?

Comment: Its about 500 kb

Comment: Looks like you're trying to pluck out `Devices` nodes from deeper in the hierarchy than you actually are. Try [`.XPathSelectElements("//Devices")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelements) if you want to be lazy about it (or properly stack the `Element` calls to get to the right spot -- `.Element("System").Element("DewesoftSetup").Elements("Devices")`).

Comment: The size is not a problem. 500 kb is a relatively small file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

> c#

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(DewesoftDevices.xmlFileName)
var devices = xdoc.Descendants("Devices");
foreach (XElement x in devices)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);

}
```